# Using alert for a readfile() function in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have this code that I want to View / Save the files (.txt) being displayed. The code for Save is working but I want the View option to show the contents of the file using an alert (I tried new tab but it shows the path in the address bar which I don't want to happen).

The problem is it shows the content under the last file being displayed and what it shows in the alert window is just a number. Is it possible to show the entire content of the file in the alert window?

```
    $dir = "C:/xampp/htdocs/www/backup";

echo "<center>";
echo "<h1>Logs</h1>";

// Open a directory, and read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
        if ($file == '.' or $file == '..'){ continue;}
        echo $file."<a href='?link=$file'>[VIEW]</a>&nbsp;<a href='?link1=$file'>[SAVE]</a> <br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
    closedir($dh);
  }
}

//View File
if(isset($_GET['link'])){
$link=$_GET['link'];
    if (is_dir($dir)){
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
                if ($link == $file){
                        $file = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/www/backup/'.$link;
                        if (file_exists($file)) {
                            //header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
                            $read = readfile($file);
                            echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert($read); </script>";
                            exit;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readfile` reads a file and writes it directly to the output buffer i.e. sends it directly to the browser.

So change the `readfile` to `file_get_contents()` for example.

You might need to wrap the resulting string in quotes to make it valid javascript as well.

```
$read = file_get_contents($file);
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('$read'); </script>";
exit;
```

Comment: I also tried file_get_contents but it does not produce an alert when view is clicked.

Comment: OH ITS WORKING NOW! THANK YOU VERY MUCH! I forgot to add the single quotes you mentioned

Comment: Done. Thank you very much!